# How can I add an image to a custom WiX dialog?

Tags: image, wix, customdialog

I have tried modifying the set of WixVariables in my Product.wxs like so:

```
<WixVariable Id="MainLogoBmp" Value="Resources/Images/weblabel.jpg" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Resources/Images/installer_banner.jpg" />
```

(The first part is what I tried, the one below it is an example of the stock variable that works)

...and then referencing the variable with !(wix.MainLogoBmp):

```
<Control Id="Bitmap"
         Type="Bitmap"
         X="0"
         Y="0"
         Width="258"
         Height="185"
         TabSkip="no"
         Text="!(wix.MainLogoBmp)" />
```

...but when I try to compile this I get the following error:

Error   17  ICE17: Bitmap: 'Resources/Images/weblabel.jpg' for Control: 'Bitmap' of Dialog: 'SimpleDlg' not found in Binary table

And yes the image is part of the project, set to "Content" like the other ones.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Aha, turns out I needed to add a `Binary` element to the file:

```
<Binary Id="MainImage" SourceFile="Resources/Images/weblabel.jpg" />
```

...and to set the `Text` of the Bitmap `Control` to "MainImage":

```
            <Control Id="Bitmap"
                        Type="Bitmap"
                        X="0"
                        Y="0"
                        Width="258"
                        Height="185"
                        TabSkip="no"
                        Text="MainImage" />
```

and now it works. :)

Comment: Just throwing this out here: BMP/JPG only! MSI does not like PNG's.