# Wix custom dialog throwing validation errors after including default bitmap

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have developed a custom dialog and follwed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277809/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-custom-wix-dialog) answer to include the default bitmap in it

```
<UI>
  <Dialog Id="DlgDbSettings" Width="420" Height="270">
    <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)"/> <!-- If I remove this line everything works fine -->
    <Control Type="Text" Id="lblHeader" Width="333" Height="17" X="8" Y="56">
      <Text>Por favor, especifique los siguientes datos requeridos para la configuración de .</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Type="Text" Id="lblIp" Width="129" Height="17" X="11" Y="82">
      <Text>IP de base de datos:</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Type="Edit" Id="txtIp" Width="190" Height="15" X="98" Y="82" />
    <Control Type="Text" Id="lblPort" Width="50" Height="17" X="11" Y="101">
      <Text>Puerto:</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Type="Edit" Id="txtPort" Width="190" Height="15" X="98" Y="101">
      <Text></Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Type="Text" Id="lblInstancia" Width="50" Height="17" X="11" Y="120">
      <Text>Instancia:</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Type="Edit" Id="txtInstancia" Width="190" Height="15" X="98" Y="120">
      <Text></Text>
    </Control>
  </Dialog>
</UI>
```

After that, my setup project doesn't compile. I get ICE validation errors:

```
Error       ICE90: Error 2242: ...\AppData\Local\Temp\2fda5qzz\Setup.msi, _Profile, ALTER TABLE `Directory` ADD `_Profile` SHORT TEMPORARY HOLD Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0   
Error       ICE64: Error 2242: ...\AppData\Local\Temp\2fda5qzz\Setup.msi, _Profile, ALTER TABLE `Directory` ADD `_Profile` SHORT TEMPORARY HOLD Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0   
Error       ICE90: ICE Internal Error 1001. API Returned: 1615. Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0   
Error       ICE43: Error 2235: ...\AppData\Local\Temp\2fda5qzz\Setup.msi, _Profile, UPDATE `Shortcut`,`Directory` SET `Shortcut`.`_ICE43Mark`=1 WHERE (`Shortcut`.`Directory_`=`Directory`.`Directory`) AND (`Directory`.`_Profile`<>2) Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0   
Error       ICE43: Error 2235: ...\AppData\Local\Temp\2fda5qzz\Setup.msi, _Profile, UPDATE `Directory` SET `_Profile`=0 Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0   
Error       ICE91: Error 2242: ...\AppData\Local\Temp\2fda5qzz\Setup.msi, _Profile, ALTER TABLE `Directory` ADD `_Profile` SHORT TEMPORARY HOLD Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0   
Error       ICE43: ICE Internal Error 4. API Returned: 1615.    Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0   
Error       ICE43: ICE Internal Error 1002. API Returned: 1615. Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0   
Error       ICE91: ICE Internal Error 1001. API Returned: 1615. Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0   
Error       ICE64: ICE Internal Error 1001. API Returned: 1615. Setup   ...\AppData\Local\Temp\biq0ectt\Setup.msi   0
```

If I remove the bitmap tag, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it, I leave the answer just for the records.

Closing Visual Studio, and deleting the %temp% folder content solved the problem. After that the project compiles fine.